# how to replace a key-value pair for a key in json file using python

Tags: python, json

```
    {
    "xyz" : {
        "SERVER": "xxx@localhost",
        "WEBHCAT_SERVER": "http://qws.qs.i5.internal.cloudapp.net:50111/templeton/v1/",

    },
    "SNSPARK": {
        "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/projects",
        "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/scripts",
        "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/databrik"
    },
    "LOCAL": {
        "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/pica/Installation/databricks/platform/projects",
        "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/pica/Installation/databricks/platform/scripts",
        "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/pica",
        "CB_URL_BASE": "http://11.222.222.111:3017/api/v1"
    },
    "DEFAULT_BACKEND": "LOCAL",
    "public": {
        "USE_LDAP": false
    }
}
```

I have above json file for which i want to change the value for all keys under "LOCAL"key that is through a python code my json file should change to the following :

```
{
        "xyz" : {
            "SERVER": "xxx@localhost",
            "WEBHCAT_SERVER": "http://qws.qs.i5.internal.cloudapp.net:50111/templeton/v1/",

        },
        "SNSPARK": {
            "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/projects",
            "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/scripts",
            "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/databrik"
        },
        "LOCAL": {
            "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/louis/databricks/platform/projects",
            "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/louis/databricks/platform/scripts",
            "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/louis",
            "CB_URL_BASE": "http://22.222.222.22:3017/api/v1"
        },
        "DEFAULT_BACKEND": "LOCAL",
        "public": {
            "USE_LDAP": false
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help in this please ?

Comment: So you want to replace `Installation` with `louis`, correct? Your input is not valid JSON, the 4th line has a trailing comma `,`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
import json

d = """{
    "xyz" : {
        "SERVER": "xxx@localhost",
        "WEBHCAT_SERVER": "http://qws.qs.i5.internal.cloudapp.net:50111/templeton/v1/"

    },
    "SNSPARK": {
        "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/projects",
        "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/scripts",
        "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/databrik"
    },
    "LOCAL": {
        "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/pica/Installation/databricks/platform/projects",
        "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/pica/Installation/databricks/platform/scripts",
        "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/pica",
        "CB_URL_BASE": "http://11.222.222.111:3017/api/v1"
    },
    "DEFAULT_BACKEND": "LOCAL",
    "public": {
        "USE_LDAP": false
    }
}"""

d = json.loads(d)
for k in d["LOCAL"]:
    d["LOCAL"][k] = d["LOCAL"][k].replace("pica/Installation", "louis")

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "SNSPARK": {
    "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/projects",
    "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/databrik/newdp/scripts",
    "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/databrik"
  },
  "DEFAULT_BACKEND": "LOCAL",
  "public": {
    "USE_LDAP": false
  },
  "LOCAL": {
    "PROJECT_BASE": "/home/pica/louis/databricks/platform/projects",
    "SCRIPT_BASE": "/home/pica/louis/databricks/platform/scripts",
    "DATA_FILE_BASE": "/home/pica",
    "CB_URL_BASE": "http://11.222.222.111:3017/api/v1"
  },
  "xyz": {
    "WEBHCAT_SERVER": "http://qws.qs.i5.internal.cloudapp.net:50111/templeton/v1/",
    "SERVER": "xxx@localhost"
  }
}
```

Comment: how to take the contents of json from a json file? and put it back to same .json file

Comment: Use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)  and [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump). Read the documentation.

Comment: Please don't put code into comments. Especially Python code is unreadable without proper indention.